# Degraded insert performance in SQL Server 2017 comparing with 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2017

I have 2 identical virtual machines: the first with SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, and the second with SQL Server 2017 Developer; all configurations and parameters on both machines are the same.

`INSERT` on SQL Server 2008 R2 is more than two times faster than on SQL Server 2017. What could be the problem?

```
USE tempdb;
GO 

BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #T(I INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, J INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #T(J) VALUES(0);

DECLARE @I INT = 10; 

WHILE @I > 0
BEGIN
    SET @I -= 1

    INSERT INTO #T
        SELECT J FROM #T;
END 

EXEC sp_spaceused 'tempdb..#t';
COMMIT TRAN;
GO

DROP TABLE #T;
```

Comment: Could you post actual execution times for both + IO statistics? For me it looks it subsecond so the comparison does not make sense. Plus please note that SQL Server 2017 by default uses multiple files for tempdb where SQL Server 2008 has single file.

Comment: Try to do the same with 100K iterations and see if it will be the same difference

Comment: Cardinality estimator has changed too

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Target Recover Time (Seconds) to 0 or to some higher value. This will prevent indirect checkpoints on which the worker thread has to wait. The default value changed from 0 to 60 between SQL Server 2014 and 2016.